# After upgrading Spring Boot version to 2.7 Flowable engine not able create table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-boot-maven-plugin, flowable

I have updated spring-boot-starter-parent dependency version to 2.7.1 and flowable-engine to 6.8.0
then after when I am running JUnit test cases then I am getting below error

```
> nested exception is org.flowable.common.engine.api.FlowableException: couldn’t create db schema: create table ACT_HI_TSK_LOG (column names .....)
..
..
..
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSqlNonTransmissionException: Unknown data type: "IDENTITY"; SQL Statement: create table ACT_HI_TSK_LOG (ID_ identity, TYPE_ varchar(64), TASK_ID_ varchar(64) not null, .....)
```

Getting same error for creating `ACT_EVT_LOG` table

I don't have defined or written this tables and I think this is coming from the flowable-engine dependency.

Dependencies which I have used :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flowable</groupId>
    <artifactId>flowable-engine</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Can someone help me on this please.

If I am using Spring `2.6.x` version then it's working fine and all JUnit test cases are getting passed

**GETTING BELOW ERROR AFTER UPGRADING THE SPRING-BOOT-STARTER-PARENT v2.7.7**

> H2 is on v1.4.200 And flowable-engine v6.8.0

```
Error creating bean with name 'processEngine': FactoryBean threw the exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while initializing Database connection at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) .........
................
ommitted caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while initializing Database connection at
...................
......................
org.flowable.spring/SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.java:76) at org.flowable.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:59) at
org.flowable.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:32) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:169) ... 65 common frames omitted Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The drive could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Socket Layer (SSL) exception. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:a31221-r15-erer-gdf45451 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3680) at 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:2047) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3204) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2833) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2671) at
```

Comment: `flowable-engine v6.8.0` does not support `H2 v2.x` (which is shipped with `spring-boot v2.7`), either switch to previous version of `H2` or run `H2` in [legacy mode](https://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) or move off from `H2`

Comment: After downgrading the H2 to 1.4.200 it's working fine, Thanks !

Comment: Hi, After downgrading H2 it's working in my local system and all test cases getting passes. 

But my deployment is getting fail with error "Error creating bean with name 'processEngine': FactoryBean threw the exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while initializing Database connection at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ........."

Comment: I have dependencies and it's version like, H2 v1.4.200, flowable-engine v6.7.2 and spring-boot-starter-parent v2.7.7

I am facing this issue after only upgrading the spring-boot-starter-parent dependency version, Before it was on 2.4.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: are you deploying on H2 as well? what is complete stacktrace?

Comment: Hi @AndreyB.Panfilov I have updated the question with detailed logs, I hope it will help you to find the exact problem
I think it looks like database connection issue, Please suggest. Thanks for your help

Comment: that is **not related** to H2, your application fails to connect to MSSQL due to some TLS certificate issues.

Comment: But it's only I am facing while I am updating the spring-boot-starter-parent v2.7.7 
If I am downgrading the spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.1-SNAPSHOT then I am not getting any deployment error and deployment getting success

Comment: This works for me   <version>1.4.200</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>

Comment: But the h2-console doesn't work for me in 1.4.200.. Switching h2 back to runtime/2.x, h2 console works. .But flowable doesn't work.